# MySQL query for device monitoring

Tags: mysql

I need your help. I try to develop monitoring of messages from devices and face some problems with SQL query. I have DB with 4 tables: devices - messages - levels - actions.

> **devices:** id, name;
>   **actions:** id, name;
>   **levels:** id, action_id, msgcount;
>   **messages:** id, action_id, device_id;

Idea is that each devices sending messages about different actions. This messages registered in 'messages' table. Each action has different amount of levels with count of messages to get this level. I want to count registered messages and show in UI progress to next level and som additioonal info. I use following query:

```
select
   mpd.action_id,
   mpd.total,
   lvl.id as lvl_id,
   lvl.msgcount purpose,
   lvl.name as level_name,
   act.name as action

from
   (select
       mes.action_id,
       count(1) total
    from
       messages mes,
       devices dev
    where
       mes.device_id=dev.id
       and dev.id=5
       and mes.action_id not in(select
                                    t.action_id
                                from
                                    messages t
                                where
                                    mes.device_id=t.device_id
                                    and t.date > CURDATE())
    group by
       mes.action_id) mpd,
    actions act,
    levels lvl

where
    mpd.action_id = act.id
    and mpd.action_id = lvl.action_id
    and lvl.msgcount = (SELECT
                            MIN(bad.msgcount)
                        FROM
                            levels lv
                        WHERE
                            lv.msgcount > mpd.total
                            and lv.action_id = mpd.action_id)
```

*mpd - messages pro device

But problem is that if top level already recieved this action no more shown in the list. But in this case I want to show the last recieved level(max) and total count of messages. Could someone please help me.

And also I will be very appreciated if you give some advices how to imrove my query.

```
    devices
|------|---------|
|  id  |  name   |
|------|---------|
|   3  | RH-SW-12|
|   5  | HRS-PR  |
|   6  | PRS-PR  |
|------|---------|

             levels
|------|-----------|----------|--------|
|  id  | action_id | msgcount |  name  |
|------|-----------|----------|--------|
|  1   |    42     |    3     |  low   |
|  2   |    51     |    3     |  start |
|  3   |    51     |    7     | medium |
|  4   |    51     |    15    |  hight |
|------|-----------|----------|--------|

        actions
|------|--------------|
|  id  |     name     |
|------|--------------|
|  42  | connection   |
|  51  | stop service |
|------|--------------|


          messages
|------|-------------|------------|----------------|
|  id  |  action_id  |  device_id |  date-time     |
|------|-------------|------------|----------------|
|  1   |     42      |      3     |14.09.2017 08:51|
|  2   |     42      |      5     |14.09.2017 13:08|
|  3   |     42      |      5     |14.09.2017 16:30|
|  4   |     42      |      5     |15.09.2017 07:43|
|  5   |     51      |      3     |15.09.2017 07:50|
|  6   |     51      |      3     |15.09.2017 10:22|
|  7   |     51      |      3     |15.09.2017 15:11|
|  8   |     51      |      3     |15.09.2017 18:48|
|  9   |     51      |      3     |15.09.2017 19:03|
|  10  |     51      |      5     |15.09.2017 19:18|
|  11  |     42      |      5     |15.09.2017 21:33|
|------|-------------|------------|----------------|
```

My query now will show following result for device 5:

```
|------------|---------|----------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
| action_id  |  total  |  lvl_id  |  purpose  |  level_name  |  action      |
|------------|---------|----------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|      51    |    1    |    2     |    3      |    start     | stop service |
|------------|---------|----------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
```

there is no info about action 42 represented because it has no more levels. Last level was "low" and it was reached.
I want modify the query to get in this case the next result for the device 5:

```
|------------|---------|----------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
| action_id  |  total  |  lvl_id  |  purpose  |  level_name  |  action      |
|------------|---------|----------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
|      42    |    4    |    1     |    3      |     low      |  connection  |
|      51    |    1    |    2     |    3      |    start     | stop service |
|------------|---------|----------|-----------|--------------|--------------|
```

I hope it's possible :)

Comment: Can you share an example with data in all the 4 tables with expected output and what output you are getting now.

Comment: @HatimStovewala Hi, i added some examples above

Comment: Why your messages table has duplicate rows? I can see for device id 5 there are 4 rows with action id as 42.

Comment: @HatimStovewala This is registered messages, which came from devices. I added also date-time column. Messages it's like history table.

Comment: Ok. You want the row to be shown if count of messages received for a particular device_id,action_id in messages table should be more than or equal to msgcount for that particular action_id in levels table. It is like a benchmark I suppose. For example, for device_id = 5 and action_id = 42, we have 4 rows in messages so its level will be "low" as msgcount >= 3 for action_id = 42 in levels table.

Comment: @HatimStovewala Yeah! :) Exactly. If there is no more higher level available, the query should show the last one (highest) and count of messages. But before - progress to the next level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes discussion with right people helps to take a look at the problem from another side. During trying different variant with answer from @HatimStovewala I found right solution:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        device_id, action_id, COUNT(1) AS count
    FROM
        messages
    WHERE 
        device_id = 5
    GROUP BY device_id , action_id) tmp,
    levels lvl
WHERE
    lvl.action_id = tmp.action_id
  and lvl.msgcount = (SELECT 
                        CASE COALESCE(MIN(msgcount),0) WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT MAX(msgcount) FROM levels WHERE action_id = tmp.action_id) ELSE MIN(repetitions) END AS rep
                      FROM
                        levels
                      WHERE
                        action_id=tmp.action_id
                        and msgcount >= tmp.count)
```

Thank you, Hatim!

Comment: Thanks mate!! Glad that it helped other way round.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will give you the current levels.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    devices d,
    actions a,
    (SELECT 
        device_id, action_id, COUNT(1) AS count
    FROM
        messages
    GROUP BY device_id , action_id) m,
    levels l
WHERE
    d.id = m.device_id
        AND a.id = m.action_id
        AND l.action_id = a.id
        AND m.count >= l.msgcount
        AND d.id = 5;
```